# Develop application over SCTP

Tags: netty, sctp

We are starting development of an application that will use SCTP protocol both as client and server.

As per documentation it seems that SCTP is included in Netty 4.0.

Can we use Netty 4.0 now for development for SCTP?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can but be aware that its still in alpha state so you may see some api-breakage before it become final. That said, I think its fair to say that the API is quite stable atm. So don't expect to many breakage.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Is there any timelines for final version SCTP api release?

Comment: Not yet.. But I suspect we will cut the first beta next month and a month later final. So we are really "near" ;)

Comment: I am little bit confused here, i am able to find sctp related code in zip and gz release[not having jars, only netty code]. However when i am taking bz2 release - alpha3 release. It is having jars and source code in jars but no sctp related classes present in jars

Comment: FYI, I have create a library that makes it easy to create protocol clients/servers using Netty's SCTP support: https://github.com/timboudreau/scamper